# onSaveInstanceState/onPause - wait until state is fully saved before allowing process to be killed

Tags: android, multithreading, lifecycle

I'm working on my first Android app. It has a model that is persisted to a database as the user makes updates.

When `onSaveInsanceState` is called, I want to save an id that can be used to load the document the user was working on from the database. But this can only happen once the document has fully hit the database. In some cases, persisting a complex document can take several seconds (I'm hoping this will speed up once I take all the verbose logging out, and in actual use a complex document will be built up by the user in stages, each of which will be persisted to the database, so it's not very likely for a complex document to have to all be saved in one go).

Now, the #1 rule of threading on Android is "don't block the UI thread", so of course the DB interactions happen on a separate thread. But my understanding of the Android lifecycle is that in many cases onSaveInstanceState is being called because the Android system wants to kill the process. That suggests I can't allow this method to return until the DB thread finishes saving the document (and in fact with my current design, I don't actually know what the id number of the document is until it's been saved to the DB, so I can't even put that in the bundle of saved state).

Is it appropriate under these circumstances to block the UI thread waiting for the persist task to be done? When `onSaveInstanceState` is called because the process is being killed, the app is no longer visible in the foreground, so there's no interface to become unresponsive.

But `onSaveInstanceState` is also called when the Activity instance is being trashed by a config update, which happens when the screen orientation changes. It's very unfortunate when rotating the screen sideways fails to do anything for several seconds. In this case the process (and therefore memory space) is still around, so I don't strictly need to ensure the document hits the database, if I can just store a reference to it in the Bundle instead of its id. But I'm not aware of a way to tell the difference between these two cases.

Is there an accepted practice for these situations? Should I just block the thread to be safe? Can I just use normal Java thread primitives to block and wait? Is there something I can do that *doesn't* block the thread but ensures the persist task will be finished before Android closes the process?

All this also applies to `onPause`, as `onSaveInstanceState` isn't necessarily going to be called.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do to the persistent saving in `onSaveInstanceState`, you can pretty much just save the instance state in the `Bundle` so that the instance can be quickly resumed in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

The Documentation states that you should write crucial persistent data (such as user edits) to storage in `onPause`, but it also states that it should be fast so that the next activity can start doing whatever it is it wants to do.

I think my recommendation here would be to just save the document text and whatever in the Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState`. Use `onPause` to save a "backup copy" somewhere fast (temporary file maybe?) which can then be restored in `onResume` if it hasn't been saved to the database. And use `onStop` (which is called when the activity is already in the background) to actually save the data to the database.

Note that the activity might get killed after `onPause` has been called (never before, unless the system has very very few resources left...), that's why I would save a quick backup before trying to commit it in the database.

**Edit - Extra based on comments**

To make sure the background thread that's doing the saving process is done saving before the application can be killed by the system, *I think* it's fine to block and wait for the saving thread to complete before returning from `onPause` but I recommend using `android:configChanges="orientation"` to prevent activity restart (and `onPause` call) when the orientation changes.

Comment: I actually commit everything to the database as soon as its written. I don't do it in `onSaveInstanceState`. The trouble is that the last triggered save operation *might be still ongoing* when `onSaveInstanceState` is called. I need to know how to wait to tell the Android system "it's okay to kill me now" until the persistent data is actually safe. If the system is so low on resources that it arbitrarily kills my process anyway, it's okay to lose unpersisted edits, but I don't want the process killed halfway through a DB operation under normal operating conditions.

Comment: In that case you can skip the `onSaveInstanceState` by using android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest file as suggested by mak_just4anything. Just make sure the saving is done in `onPause`/`onStop`. More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: I'm obviously not making my question understood. Lets say my `onPause` calls `tellBackgroundThreadToSaveStateToDb`. Good. Done. Now, how do I ensure the background thread isn't still processing that request when Android wants to kill my process?

Comment: If you're using `AsyncTask` or `FutureTask` you can use the get method to block until the thread is done processing. If not, block some other way...

Comment: So blocking the UI thread is the thing to do under these circumstances? Cool, that's what I was asking. Feel free to make that an answer, so I can accept it if nothing else comes along.

Answer (score 0):

You should try AsyncTask, which will block your ui but wont show blank screen, will load the necessary xml elements and then will get call from Async task, in async task save your doc in database.

Follow this link: [AyncTask Exmaple](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/)

Comment: I thought the point of `AsyncTask` was that it *doesn't* block the UI thread? Isn't that the whole point of using it to do long-lasting operations?

Comment: If you are having problems on changes of Config then dont worry, just write down the configChanges in your mainfest file in this activity tag, so it wll never call onSaveInstanceState() when the orientation is changed. It wont force activity to get restarted

Comment: That's handy (but has its own problems), but is completely irrelevant to the question, which is how do I ensure persistent data us actually saved when the app is killed if the saving is done by a background thread.